# Is there a finance API of some kind to get all holdings for a specific mutual fund?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, online-data-source

Is there a finance API out there that easily allows pulling of all the stock holdings of a specific mutual fund?

Comment: I was thinking the United States.

Comment: Mutual funds generally do not make their holdings available to the public on a day-to-day (or minute-by-minute) basis, but do report them (on a less-frequent basis) to their shareholders.

Comment: not sure about mutual fund, but for ETF, you can try this:http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/Fund/IVV and then click on 'Holdings'

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the answer to the availability of holdings of a given mutual fund on a daily basis is no. Thus, an API is non-existent.

The reasons for the lack of transparency on a daily basis is that it could/would impact the portfolio managers ability to trade. While this information would not necessarily permit individuals from front running the fund manager's trades, it does give insight in to the market outlook and strategy the fund is employing.

The closest you'll be able to get to obtaining a list of holdings is by reading the most recent annual report and the quarterly filings each fund is required to file with the SEC.